# View the campaign terms for only a specific medium In Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, marketing, campaigns, search-terms

I'm using the `utm_term` parameter for links in my email campaigns. I'd like to filter out the parameter from my master profiles. That is, removing `utm_term=keyword` for visits with `utm_medium=email`, so the organic keyword results are not skewed, while having a view which includes the term for further analysis.

What are the correct order and filters to accomplish this?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this.   I use `utm_term` for the name of the website on which the advertisement appears when advertising on Google AdWord's content network.  I'd like to be able to separate out the term used in the content network compaigns from the term used in the search network campaign (which is a real keyword that the user had searched for.)

Comment: As far as organic goes, I don't have a problem separating out the campaign terms from the organic terms.  "Acquisition" -> "Keywords" -> "Organic" has just the keywords from non-paid search with none of the campaign `utm_keyword` terms mixed in.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller why wouldn't you use Source, or Medium as the name of the website on which the advertisement was displayed. You'd then be able to create a custom report showing the source or medium , being the website the ad was displayed on. Then filter by acquisition method

Comment: I've set it up with: campaign: July 2014, source: google_adwords_content_network, medium: cpc, keyword: {placement}.   I suppose cpc is the one I least care about between source and medium, if I were to choose one of those to replace.  But then I think it would make it difficult to see just the content network traffic as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Anagio here. It is a matter of a best practice.

The campaign name should be "Adwords Content Network", and the Source should have {placement}. You can also append "adwords content network: {placement}" if you want this field clearer in your reports.

If your campaigns are time-based then make the campaign name "Adwords content network July 2014".